# How to add an empty line between two formulars

Tags: line-breaking

I have the following code

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\underline{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}

\begin{math}
P_j(t,s_j) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{for } t < s_j \\
        Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{for  }s_j \leq t\leq s_j+p_j  \\
        0 & \text{for  } t>s_j+p_j 
   \end{cases}
    \end{math}

    \newline

  \begin{math}  
  \text{with }s_j = r_j+ \Delta t\\
      \Delta t\leq tDoF
  \end{math}

\end{document}
```

And I would like to add an empty line between the two math-parts. Unfortunately the command `\newline` or `\\` does not work in this context. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`math` is the same as `\(` or `$` and designed for *inline* math not displays. You want a display environment such as `equation` or `align` that will automatically offset the expression with vertical space and not require forced adjustments, for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\section*{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}

\begin{equation*}
P_j(t,s_j) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{for } t < s_j \\
        Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{for  }s_j \leq t\leq s_j+p_j  \\
        0 & \text{for  } t>s_j+p_j 
   \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
with
  \begin{align*}  
  s_j = r_j+ \Delta t\\
      \Delta t\leq tDoF
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```